# Not working jsp session parse to integer

Tags: java, jsp, parsing, session, int

> `String counter=(String) request.getSession().getAttribute("count");
>   int count = Integer.parseInt(counter);`

I get this stupid error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String and i really dont know what to do help please

Comment: The above code should work Because Object class can be cased to String.. There is not problem in the above code. Can you please post your exception trace?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch See the API doc (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). The return type of getAttribute is Object . So there is nothing wrong in casting it to String. The OP may be getting exception due to other code.

Comment: @Stunner I am aware that the return type is Object. OP has an `Integer` (which is a wrapper type for `int`). And you can't cast from Object to String. That's why Object has `toString()`. You could try `System.out.println((String) ((Object) ((Integer) 1)));` which will match the Exception OP provided *java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String*.

Answer (score 1):

That `Exception` is telling you that the session attribute `count` is an `Integer` in the session. You could cast it to an `Integer` and let Java unbox it for you like,

```
int count = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("count");
```

Or (if you want to use it as a `String`) like,

```
String counter = request.getSession().getAttribute("count").toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to

```
Object o = request.getSession().getAttribute("count");
```

And check which type `o` has in the debugger. If the type is `Integer`, change your code to

```
Integer counter = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("count");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `.getAttribute("count");` is getting Integer value then no need to cast it to String first. Rather Cast it to `int count` directly.

```
int count = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("count");
```